# Input split in Haddop Streaming

Tags: python-2.7, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, oozie-workflow

I am using hadoop streaming via a python script to attach prediction scores to data using a pre-trained model. My data is organized as follows:

/user/..../idType=id1/part-0000.csv
/user/..../idType=id1/part-0001.csv
.
.
/user/..../idType=id2/part-0000.csv
/user/..../idType=id2/part-0001.csv
.
.
and so on.

I read the file name in the python script and attach the idType from the file name to the other fields for the record including prediction score. The problem I am facing is that the records are getting different idType than the one they belong to. I think this is because of the way hadoop streaming works where a mapper read from multiple splits for a particular task. How can I solve this problem where I want to attach the idType from the file name for the records while processing that file? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. in the Map phase, how are you getting the `idType` can you post the code?

Comment: I mean, yes the file is going to be chunk but then in the reduced phase, you can combine it again.

Comment: The Inputformat defines InputSplit and RecordReader. But I think the problem here is not the way you access the file, is that you are not doing a reduced phase very well. Please post the code, maybe I can help you with it.

Comment: I have a python script in which i get the file_name using os.environ and get idType from that filename. Then I read the records from the csv, predict a score using a model and attach the idType as a column since that record belong to a partition with the above idType. Somehow the records get different idType, which I am trying to figure out. Am i clear? @KenrySanchez

Comment: so `i  get the file_name using os.environ and get idType from that filename.` this is not working well. I got it.